# Mariabackup Throws Unknown Argument Error

Tags: mariadb, ssl

I have just installed the MariaDB backup tool based on Percona Xtrabackup, Mariabackup, on my CentOS 7 system with MariaDB v10.1. However, when I try to test using this tool, it fails immediately complaining about an unknown argument.

I tried running this command as a full backup, as a full backup using the `--xbstream` option to pipe it through gzip, and as a full backup using gzip and OpenSSL. I also tried GPG with gzip.

Here are the commands I've tried:

With gzip/openssl:

```
mariabackup --user=root --password= `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow ` --backup     --stream=xbstream | gzip | openssl  enc -aes-256-cbc -k password123 >     backup.xb.gz.enc
```

with gzip/gpg:

```
mariabackup --user=root --password= `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow ` --backup --stream=xbstream | gzip | gpg -c --passphrase password123 --batch --yes -o backup.xb.gzip.gpg
```

With gzip:

```
mariabackup --user=root --password= `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow ` --backup --stream=xbstream | gzip > backup.xb.gz
```

And just straight up:

```
mariabackup --user=root --password= `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow ` --backup --target-dir=/root/sql_dumps/
```

And here's the output:

Info: Using unique option prefix 'backup' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name `backup_encrypted` instead.

```
mariabackup: Error: unknown argument: '$AES-128-CBC$GzzuTl0rBKRyCngfmWSypg==$JAmMp9hcbIQ/MTrzqCQ8eWIFQGixpUjZ7ESQqNLfuJM='
```

Comment: Something fundamental to this is broken on my machine. I simply used the yum tool to install MariaDB-backup and this was the result. It appears I'll have to find a new solution, which is a shame because this should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this error was caused by supplying the wrong username. After I resolved that, the error went away and the backup initiated.